# Swiper.js React compile failing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm trying to update the [swiper.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper)  library

I was using swiper version: **6.8.2**,

Now I would like to upgrade it to a newer version **7.4.1**

My App is written in React and Node js with SSR( I'm not using Next.js) and Node version: v14.11.0

Here is how my component code, looks like

```
import React from 'react'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'

const CustomView = () => {

  return (
      <Swiper>
      </Swiper>
  )
}


export default CustomView
```

When I run it I'm getting the following error in terminal

```
"message":"Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/Projects/ReactStarter/node_modules/swiper/react/swiper-react.js\nrequire() of ES modules is not supported.
```

Then I change Import to:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js'
```

In Terminal error is printed:

```
"message":"Package subpath './react/swiper-react.js' is not defined by \"exports\"
```

Is there any way I can bypass this, since I'm using **webpack** so maybe I can somehow ignore it or something else

Comment: have you tried any of these options ?  https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/1622

Comment: Yes saw that thread, none of the solutions worked for me unfortunately :(

Comment: What is your node version? Can you share your webapack config?

Answer (score 0):

can u try in terminal

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm rm -rf node_modules`

and install again 3. `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with next.js a temporary fix would be changing `experimental.esmExternals` to `loose` in your `next.config.js` and follow [this thread](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/5056) for more updates regarding this issue.

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    esmExternals: "loose",
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the library might not be a option.
Considering you are using React 18.
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871